# How internet browsers trigger flash application with .jpg extension?

Tags: http, browser, mime

Today I came across a shock site with a big picture of a girl's face blinking and loud screaming in the background.

The surprise is that although it seems to be a static image, in fact it's an `application/x-shockwave-flash` file. The browser (Firefox in my case) displays it correctly as a Flash application. And my question is - how can the browser know that it's not a JPG image but rather a Flash application? Does it use heuristic techniques or is there a hidden "flag" in the file?

When I inspect the page in Firebug, I get this:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height;">
    <title>anne.jpg (application/x-shockwave-flash objekt)</title>
 </head>
 <body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
   <embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="http://akk.li/pics/anne.jpg" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
 </body>
</html>
```

So the browser obviously knows what the file format is. But how?

Comment: Extensions mean absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server returns the file with the `Content-Type: application/x-shockwave-flash` header.